# Is it possible to return integer result from Linq Average method, without casting double result to int?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, average

```
int[] arr = {1,4,5,6,7,2,4,5,6,8,0};

int averageResult = arr.Average(); //?? How to return Average int result. Without casting/convert
```

In this example, can we obtain int result  from Average method, **without casting/convert** ?

Comment: What's wrong with "casting/convert"? Why don't you want to do it?

Comment: I am curious about if average method has an option that return int result.

Comment: No, there is no overload of [`Average`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.average?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-average(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-nullable((system-decimal)))))) that returns an `int`.

Comment: Why would it? What are the chances that summing a list of integers will produce a multiple of their count? That would be rare. It makes far more sense that it would return a `double` because the result will almost never be a whole number. If you want to round the result then you should do that explicitly.

Comment: If you read the documentation then you know that that method returns a `double` and that's all there is to it, so the question is pointless. I didn't make any comments that were a judgement on you.  I merely pointed out what you did wrong. If no one tells you what you're doing wrong, you won't know to change what you're doing. If people do point it out and you still do it then it's not surprising that you would assume that people will judge you.

Comment: @John I do not need your comments. Thanks. Bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Average()** in LINQ returns double so there is no possibility. If you have problem with code cleanliness or you want to shorten code length, then you can do your own extension method that wraps this casting.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static int AverageInt(this int[] array)
    {
        double avg = array.Average();
        return Math.Round(avg, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    }
}
```

and then use it :D

```
int[] arr = {1,4,5,6,7,2,4,5,6,8,0};

int averageResult = arr.AverageInt();
```

Comment: If you just use `(int)` to convert the result, an average of (for example) `0.99999999` will be returned as `0.0`. You should probably be returning `Math.Round(avg, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` so that it would return `1.0` in that case.

Comment: I just wanted to point out an extension method idea but you're definitely right. I made an edit :D